# CRTP class example

Tags: c++, templates

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <class T> 
struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        // ...
        static_cast<T*>(this)->implementation();
        // ...
    }

    static void static_func()
    {
        // ...
        T::static_sub_func();
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation();
    static void static_sub_func();
};
```

It seems we're going to use `implementation()` only within the `interface()` function. So why don't we declare `implementation()` as a `private` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make `implementation()` *private*, then the base class wouldn't be able to access it. To make it able to access it, you've to make the base a friend of the derived:

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    static void static_sub_func();

   private:

    friend class Base<Derived>;  //make base friend

    void implementation();

};
```

Hope that helps.